# Hashicorp Vault for Kubernetes - Deployment can't get secret injected

Tags: kubernetes, vault

I am currently doing a PoC on Vault for K8s, but I am having some issues injecting a secret into an example application. I have created a Service Account which is associated with a role, which is then associated with a policy that allows the service account to read secrets.

I have created a secret `basic-secret`, which I am trying to inject to my example application. The application is then associated with a Service Account. Below you can see the code for deploying the example application (Hello World) and the service account:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: basic-secret
  labels:
    app: basic-secret
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: basic-secret
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: "true"
        vault.hashicorp.com/tls-skip-verify: "true"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-helloworld: "secret/basic-secret/helloworld"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-helloworld: |
          {{- with secret "secret/basic-secret/helloworld" -}}
          {
            "username" : "{{ .Data.username }}",
            "password" : "{{ .Data.password }}"
          }
          {{- end }}
        vault.hashicorp.com/role: "basic-secret-role"
      labels:
        app: basic-secret
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: basic-secret
      containers:
      - name: app
        image: jweissig/app:0.0.1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: basic-secret
  labels:
    app: basic-secret
```

When I describe the pod (`kubectl describe pod basic-secret-7d6777cdb8-tlfsw -n vault`) of the deployment I get:
[image]

Furthermore, for logs (`kubectl logs pods/basic-secret-7d6777cdb8-tlfsw vault-agent -n vault`) I get:

> Error from server (BadRequest): container "vault-agent" in pod "basic-secret-7d6777cdb8-tlfsw" is waiting to start: PodInitializing

I am not sure why the Vault-Agent is not initiallizing. If someone has any idea what might be the issue, I would appreciate it a lot!

Best William.

Answer (score 0):

1. Grab your container logs with kubectl logs pods/basic-secret-7d6777cdb8-tlfsw vault-agent-init -n vault because container vault-agent-init has to finish first.
2. Does your policy allow access to that secret (secret/basic-secret/helloworld)?
3. Did you create your role (basic-secret-role) in k8s auth? In role creation process, you can authorize certain namespaces so that might be a problem.

But, let's see those agent-init logs first